# Can't make a Windows Service invoke a child process properly on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, service

The following function I wrote is supposed to be invoked by a Windows Service in order to start a child process (as a user), so the child process can interact with the user, i.e. have UI. It works perfectly on Windows desktop but fails to work properly on Windows Server 2012. The UI isn't shown (even not a Console window) and a hot key we register for uninstalling the service, doesn't work as well.

The following code:

```
void WINAPI Run(DWORD dwTargetSessionId, int desktop, LPTSTR lpszCmdLine)
{
    wprintf(_T("Run client start"));

    if (hPrevAppProcess != NULL)
    {
        TerminateProcess(hPrevAppProcess, 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(hPrevAppProcess, INFINITE);
    }


    HANDLE hToken = 0;
    WTS_SESSION_INFO *si;
    DWORD cnt = 0;
    WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &si, &cnt);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)cnt; i++)
    {
        if (si[i].SessionId == 0)continue;
        wprintf(_T("Trying session id %i (%s) user admin token"), si[i].SessionId, si[i].pWinStationName);
        HANDLE userToken;
        if (WTSQueryUserToken(si[i].SessionId, &userToken))
        {
            wprintf(_T("WTSQueryUserToken succeced"));
            TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN admin;
            DWORD len;
            if (GetTokenInformation(userToken, TokenLinkedToken, &admin, sizeof(TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN), &len))
            {
                wprintf(_T("Success using user admin token"));
                hToken = admin.LinkedToken;
                break;
            }
            else
                wprintf(L"GetTokenInformation() failed");

            CloseHandle(userToken);
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            if (error)
            {
                LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
                DWORD bufLen = FormatMessage(
                    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL,
                    error,
                    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                    (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
                    0, NULL);
                utils::WriteLogFile(L"Error '%s'\n", lpMsgBuf);
            }
        }

    }
    if (hToken == 0)
    {
        HANDLE systemToken;
        OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &systemToken);
        DuplicateTokenEx(systemToken, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hToken);
        CloseHandle(systemToken);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < (int)cnt; i++)
        {
            if (si[i].SessionId == 0)continue;
            if (SetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenSessionId, &si[i].SessionId, sizeof(DWORD)))
            {
                wprintf(_T("Success using system token with set user session id %i"), si[i].SessionId);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == cnt)
            wprintf(_T("No success to get user admin token nor system token with set user session id"));
    }
    WTSFreeMemory(si);


    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = {};
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    startupInfo.lpDesktop = _T("winsta0\\default");

    LPVOID pEnv = NULL;
    CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv, hToken, TRUE);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = {};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo32 = {};

    TCHAR szCurModule[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szCurModule, MAX_PATH);

    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    std::wstring commandLine;
    commandLine.reserve(1024);

    commandLine += L"\"";
    commandLine += szCurModule;
    commandLine += L"\" \"";
    commandLine += SERVICE_COMMAND_LUNCHER;
    commandLine += L"\"";

    wprintf(_T("launch SG_WinService with CreateProcessAsUser ...  %s"), commandLine.c_str());

    bRes = CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, NULL, &commandLine[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS |
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, pEnv,
        NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo);

    if (bRes == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD   dwLastError = ::GetLastError();
        TCHAR   lpBuffer[256] = _T("?");
        if (dwLastError != 0)    // Don't want to see a "operation done successfully" error ;-)
            ::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,                 // It´s a system error
                NULL,                                      // No string to be formatted needed
                dwLastError,                               // Hey Windows: Please explain this error!
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),  // Do it in the standard language
                lpBuffer,              // Put the message here
                255,                     // Number of bytes to store the message
                NULL);
        (_T("CreateProcessAsUser(SG_WinService) failed - Error : %s (%i)"), lpBuffer, dwLastError);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(_T("CreateProcessAsUser(SG_WinService) success. New process ID: %i"), processInfo.dwProcessId);
    }
}
```

returns the following output:

> 05.06.2019 04:25  5856: Trying session id 1 (Console) user admin token
>
> 05.06.2019 04:25  5856: Trying session id 2 (RDP-Tcp#27) user admin token
>
> 05.06.2019 04:25  5856: Trying session id 65536 (RDP-Tcp) user admin token
>
> 05.06.2019 04:25  5856: Success using system token with set user session id 1
>
> 05.06.2019 04:25  5856: launch SG_WinService with CreateProcessAsUser ...  "C:\myservice\SG_WinService.exe" "ServiceIsLuncher"
>
> 05.06.2019 04:25  5856: CreateProcessAsUser(SG_WinService) success. New process ID: 5580

Update:
After adding a call to GetLastError(), I get:

> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: Trying session id 1 user admin token
>
> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: Error 'An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.
>
> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: Trying session id 3 user admin token
>
> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: Trying session id 65536 user admin token
>
> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: Error 'The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: Success using system token with set user session id 1
>
> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: launch SG_WinService with CreateProcessAsUser ...
>
> "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\src\SpyfiWebApp\SG_WinService.exe" "ServiceIsLuncher"
>
> 09.06.2019 04:55  6008: CreateProcessAsUser(SG_WinService) success. New process ID: 7536

So instead of running the child process on Session 1, it runs as "SYSTEM".

Comment: The first step is to figure out which function call is failing and what the error code is.  Can't do much without that.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the call to WTSQueryUserToken(si[i].SessionId, &userToken) fails when the session / account being checked is "Console" which seems to be the one we would use. This is a "user" session that would have been able to display UI

Comment: You need to call GetLastError() to get the error code.  I see there's a Remote Desktop session active, so is anyone actually logged into the physical console?  Is the code running as local system?

Comment: I did and updated the output in my question. Also I am testing via Remote Desktop, connecting me to a remote Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I found out (thanks to @HarryJohnston that the problem occurs only when I connect to a server via Remote Desktop but when I physically install the Service, it works and the UI is shown

Comment: @HarryJohnston Please explain to me why don't I see UI when I connect to a server via Remote Desktop. Isn't it the same as logging in as Administrator?

Comment: If nobody is logged onto the physical console, than attempting to fetch the user token from the Console session won't work.  You need to fetch the user token from the relevant RDP session.  In the latest posted output that will be session id 3, there's no error message there so it looks like the WTSQueryUserToken call worked.  Perhaps the attempt to get a linked token failed?  That would happen if you were logged in with a non-administrative account, for example.

Comment: ... and then the output shows that the process was launched as local system in session id 1, which explains why you can't see it, since you are logged into session id 3.

Comment: It means WTSQueryUserToken returned 0, but GetLastError didn’t return any error (dwLastError was 0).

Comment: In this specific case, it is a virtual server and I operate it via RDP using the Administrator account.

Comment: *It means WTSQueryUserToken returned 0, but GetLastError didn’t return any error* - that's extremely unlikely, I recommend you double-check this.  It is probably safest to generate an error message even if the returned error code is 0, that avoids any possible ambiguity.

Comment: You were right. So now the log looks like this:

10.06.2019 00:55  4276: Trying session id 2 (RDP-Tcp#12) user admin token
10.06.2019 00:55  4276: Success

10.06.2019 00:55  4276: GetTokenInformation failed

WTSQueryUserToken() indeed succeed but GetTokenInformation() fails

Comment: 10.06.2019 00:59  5056: Trying session id 2 (RDP-Tcp#12) user admin token
10.06.2019 00:59  5056: Success

10.06.2019 00:59  5056: GetTokenInformation failed
10.06.2019 00:59  5056: Error 'The data area passed to a system call is too small.
'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/searching-for-a-sid-in-an-access-token-in-c--

Comment: Following the explanation in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/searching-for-a-sid-in-an-access-token-in-c--, I call GetTokenInformation() twice, the 2nd time after allocating the required size in memory, and it succeed. However, now when I launch the child process from the RDP session but still no UI is shown. Log: 
- Trying session id 2 (RDP-Tcp#12) user admin token
- Success
- Success using system token with set user session id 1
- aunch SG_WinService with CreateProcessAsUser

Comment: Can you locate the bug in the source code?

Comment: You can view the entire code here: https://github.com/haephrati/win_service

Comment: The first call to GetTokenInformation is passing in `dwSize` which is uninitialized.  Should be `GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenLinkedToken, NULL, 0, &dwSize)`

Comment: I still get 11.06.2019 14:35  3540: Trying session id 0 (Services) user admin token (sessionId = 0) - continuing
11.06.2019 14:35  3540: Trying session id 1 (Console) user admin token
11.06.2019 14:35  3540: Error 'An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.

'

Comment: Remember, the session you want is the one named `RDP-Tcp` (plus a number).

Comment: Ok, in that case it gets to session 2 but no UI is shown

Comment: What I pointed to you is an error while checking session 1. If you refer to session 2, then no UI is shown

Comment: Are you sure you're actually getting a token from session 2, and not falling back to using the system token?  You might want to remove the entire "try using the system token" logic block and just abort with an error message if `htoken == 0` so as to remove the ambiguity.